# angular select not get getting set from ng-model assignment

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have a select set that I want to default to the state of a logged in user. The returned JSON for the state is the `StateCode` e.g. `"MI"`

```
<div>
  <select 
    name="ParentState" 
    ng-model="selectedState" 
    ng-options="s.StateCode for s in cStates track by s.StateID | orderBy:'StateCode'">
  </select>
</div>
```

and in my controller

```
var init = function() {
  angular.forEach(xStates, function(xS) {
    if (xS.StateCode == xParentState) {
      $scope.selectedState = xS.StateID;
      $scope.vName = "It's working!" + $scope.selectedState;
    }
  });
}

init();
```

The last line in the init function just writes out to `{{ vName }}` so that I could see the function was working and the value of `$scope.selectedState` is correct, for instance `"MI"` would be `23` but the select when the page is loaded is not set to `"MI"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a couple things could be going wrong here, and I took somewhat of a best guess as to your desired outcome. Firstly, `s.StateCode for s...` in your markup is going to fill your `<option>`'s with `StateCode`. You mention you wish to see `"MI"`, so lets indtead change this to `StateName`. Secondly, to default `$scope.selectedState` as our model, there is no need to specify `StateId` - just select the object and AngularJS will be satisfied to default our `ng-options`. Here is a completed example with some interpretations as to what I think you are after.

```
<select 
    name="ParentState" 
    ng-model="selectedState" 
    ng-options="s.StateName for s in xStates track by s.StateID | orderBy:'StateCode'">
```

---

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.xStates  = [{'StateCode': 1, 'StateID': 'A', 'StateName': 'AL'}, 
                    {'StateCode': 23, 'StateID': 'B', 'StateName': 'MI'},
                    {'StateCode': 50, 'StateID': 'C', 'StateName': 'Hawaii'}];

    angular.forEach($scope.xStates, function (xS) {
        if (xS.StateCode === 23) { // -- for demo simplicity
            $scope.selectedState = xS;
        }
    });
}]);
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/1bgeknh5/) - working demo

Comment: I should have mentioned, the JSON being passed is `[{'StateID: '1', StateCode: 'AL' ...}]`

Comment: I went ahead and edited the JSFiddle to more closely resemble my code and it is working...so I'm not sure why it's not working in my environment. https://jsfiddle.net/spacemancraig24/1bgeknh5/2/  I should mention this is a web part setup as a form in Sharepoint 2010

Comment: I cant see your environment affecting this in a negative way. What are you experiencing? And yea I had to make a best guess at the JSON setup.

Comment: I got a hold of the original developer, and yeah it looks like from a framework level in Sharepoint there is jquery mobile which is touching all the elements for styling purposes and he thinks that is prevent the select element from functioning properly with Angular.

Comment: well, disregard that, I disabled the JQuery Mobile on the web part and still not visually setting the select to the state. Just stays at the default value even though the ng-model value is getting set to the correct value.

Comment: hm I'm at a loss as to what could be going wrong. This should work for you. Are you getting any console errors? Keep me posted with your findings so we can try and help you resolve this

Comment: sorry i was out of the office for the holiday but not as of yet. I went into the master page for our sharepoint sites and removed or disable  JQuery mobile and other js applications and still no luck. Something is preventing it from working properly but still not sure what. For now I'm moving on, the ng-model is retaining the proper value and there's a chance the parent would be in a different state so I'm wondering if I need a dropdown at all.  I'll keep you posted as I work on this.

Comment: Hey @Spacemancraig just checking in to see if this is still plaguing you, or if you have found a solution or mine was able to help. Let me know!

Comment: sorry, I am still having an issue with this. After some discussions with some higher ups we determined there would be no need to change the state on this form as the applicant would have to reside within that state so instead I just pre-populate with a text field. I think the issue was still a confliction with JQuery Mobile as I can get the code working plnkr

Comment: Would you be willing to accept this an answer if the fiddles solve the concept? Thanks